# Determine IAM principal that was denied access

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I'm helping a colleague troubleshoot an S3 put "access denied" error when he uses a Python library that internally calls `boto3`. To simplify the troubleshooting process I'd like to know which IAM principal is getting denied. It's not the instance's IAM role because that role has full S3 access, so I'm trying to consider other possibilities.

Normally if I were to call the `boto3` code directly I wouldn't have this question because I would either 1) need to be explicit about the principal or 2) `boto3` would check for the presence of an environment variable such as `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, and if that wasn't set AWS would fall back to the EC2 instance's associated role / default profile (please correct me if I am wrong about this order of precedence).

How can I determine the denied principal used by a third party library other than by diving into the library's source code?

Comment: You could look into cloudtrail - however s3 data events are normally not logged by default. You could set a breakpoint deep within boto and try to figure out which credentials are used. Additionally s3:* may not be enough if the bucket / object has KMS encryption. Have you verified that a regular boot call from the instance can access the data in s3

Comment: @luk2302 I'm not sure what you mean by "boot call", but I was able to put files outside of the application from the instance. I believe in this specific case our bucket has S3 logging enabled, so now I'm going to try to query Cloud Trail with Athena.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code to identify which credentials are being used:

```py
import boto3

sts_client = boto3.client('sts')

response = sts_client.get_caller_identity()
print(response['Arn'])
```

It will show an ARN like: `arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/User-Name`

If you run it from an EC2 instance it would show an ARN like: `arn:aws:sts::123456789012:assumed-role/Role-Name/i-1234abcd`